# Save Header Names to List used to Find Column Index using Range.Find function

Tags: excel, vba, find

Currently I have a code that searches my "Sheet1" for different headers and then saves the header variable to be a string and the column number to a variable, however instead of using `Application.Match` I want to use now `.Find` What my current code does is it goes through column D saving all the cells to a dictionary. Then from that I can assign the column cell a variable in this case sysnum as a String bring `Test30,Test28` and so on. Then I also assign sysrow and syscol to represent the row and column indexes that each sysnum is in. From that I now want to look at all the headers and find the column index that each header is in. So for `Color` it should tell me that it is in column 5 for column E.

What I want the code to do is tell me for each Test in column D, ind should be equal to A, lvl should be 1 and so on for each header value that matches the test number, but then when it loops through to say Test5, then ind should = F and lvl should = 4 and so on

[Excel Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bhgl.png)

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
Sub columnlocation() 

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object
Dim indexcol As Integer, levelcolAs Integer, depthcol As Integer, testcol As Integer, colorcol As Integer, typecol As Integer

Dim ind As Long, lvl As Long, dpth As Long, tst As Long, color As Long, typ As Long 

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each i In ws.Range("D2:D15").Cells 
sysnum = i.value
sysrow = i.Row
syscol = i.Column

indexcol = Application.Match("Index", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0) 
ind = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, indexcol ) 

levelcolAs = Application.Match("Level", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
lvl = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, levelcolAs )

depthcol = Application.Match("Depth", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
dpth  = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, depthcol )

testcol = Application.Match("Test", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
tst = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, testcol )

colorcol = Application.Match("Color", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
color = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, colorcol )

typecol = Application.Match("Type", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
typ = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(sysrow, typecol )

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the question? How to replace the `Application.Match` part with a `.find` equivalent? Or is it something else? Since it, as it is, has type conflicts with the example data and no output. But maybe that is to be ignored with the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it shorter, but going with the same approach, but with `Range.Find`.
As .Find returns a range, rather than a number we have no use for the `sysrow`/`col` so it could be something like this:

```
Sub columnlocation()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, headerRange As Range, c As Range, dict As Object
Dim i As Long, ind As String, lvl As Long 
Dim dpth As String, tst As String, color As String, typ As Double

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set headerRange = ws.Range("A1:Z1")

For i = 1 To 14

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Index")
    ind = c.Offset(i).Value

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Level")
    lvl = c.Offset(i).Value

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Depth")
    dpth = c.Offset(i).Value

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Test")
    tst = c.Offset(i).Value

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Color")
    color = c.Offset(i).Value

    Set c = headerRange.Find("Type")
    typ = c.Offset(i).Value
    
    Debug.Print ind & " - " & lvl & " - " & dpth & " - " & tst & " - " & color & " - " & typ
Next i

End Sub
```

It's not saving anything in any dictionary, but neither is the example, and I'm not sure what you are doing with it. I just added a Debug.Print to show the values.

This is an example of a different approach, where we loop the headers, meaning you can att more headers without adding more lines and variables to the code.
In this example, I'm putting each header in a collection, then printing the collection when all headers are read, to then fill the collection with the next row of values.

```
Sub columnlocation()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, headRng As Range, c As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, headArr As Variant, typeCol As Collection, colItem As Variant, colString As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set headRng = ws.Range("A1:Z1")
headArr = Array("Index", "Level", "Depth", "Test", "Color", "Type")

For i = 1 To ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set typeCol = New Collection
    For j = 0 To UBound(headArr)
        Set c = headRng.Find(headArr(j))
        typeCol.Add c.Offset(i).Value
    Next j
    colString = ""
    For Each colItem In typeCol
        colString = colString & colItem & " "
    Next colItem
    Debug.Print colString
Next i

End Sub
```